# Give Access to Specify Remote IP in python BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, server

I want to Give Access to Specific Remote IP in python http Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler).

```
hostName = "192.168.1.96"
hostPort = 80

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        ip = self.client_address[0]
        print(ip)
        #50.62.117.99
        self.send_response(200)
        #print(self.client_address[0])
        if(self.client_address[0] == "50.62.117.99"):
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes("success", "utf-8"))
        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes("Not Found", "utf-8"))


myServer = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), MyServer)
print(time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))
print(time.asctime(), 'Login Facebook....')
```

Server is Working Fine But it Always return Not Found even if access from Correct IP

Comment: In your example code, you have a comment after `print(ip)` which has a value of `50.62.117.10`.  Is this the client address?  If so, it doesn't match the client_address in your `if` statement (`50.62.117.99`).

Comment: i have also fixed that